Confusion between wave frequency and photon frequency
Suppose I have some electrons in a wire which are moving up and down, in sync, where the position is given by $x = \sin(2\pi ft)$. At times $n/f$, there is no acceleration and therefore not emitting any photons. So, the intensity of the radiation I see will vary over time with a frequency of $f$.
If I understand correctly, the individual photons themselves also have frequency. Does the frequency of the photons also equal $f$?

stationary is still accelerating and thus also still radiating.

Oops, I just corrected that.

Please look https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30804/frequency-and-wavelength-of-photons?rq=1 and the answers therein

That is a very comprehensible question. You might be interested in this answer about What are photons, EM radiation and EM waves
